# Add more clock speeds

Tags: kernel, overclocking

I know that the phone's kernel contains the clock speeds but is there a way to add your own clock speeds?
What do I have to do to edit the kernel, where is the the clock speed data stored?

Comment: On most customROMs with root permissions you can configure the CPU governator which controls the clock speed for the different scenarios (idle, load and everything in between).

Comment: @robert but how to I add new clock speeds to the kernel?

Comment: As far as I know you need a rooted device and your ROM has to support CPU genvernator (not sure if this is the case for regular ROMs from Android manufactures). Please see for example this page: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/changing-cpu-governor-with-adb.4193163/